# How to Find All the Controls in a Form, During the Run Time

Tags: c#, winforms

Finding all the controls in a form by Using **"Reflection"**
During the Run Time..

Comment: why you think is necessary to use reflection ?

Comment: what's the reason behind getting all child collection of the form ? better to group controls and change their property in one go (like disabling it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Control> list = new List<Control>();

            GetAllControl(this, list);

        private void GetAllControl(Control c , List<Control> list)
        {
            foreach (Control control in c.Controls)
            {
                list.Add(control);

                if (control.Controls.Count > 0)
                    GetAllControl(control , list);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can recursively iterate through `Controls` collection on a form or another control.

But you can't get all controls at runtime with reflection if they were added to a controls collection during the program run

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
var controls = from control in this.Controls select control;
```

or if you want any specific control.

```
var textboxes = from textbox in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()                 
select textbox;
```